# CacheManager properties have been set- Apache Shiro

Tags: google-app-engine, shiro

How can I set cacheManager properties, while using Apache shiro. On debugging , I am getting INFO like,

```
80104 [1045903843@qtp-967078155-3] INFO org.apache.shiro.realm.AuthorizingRealm - No cache or cacheManager properties have been set.  Authorization cache cannot be obtained.
```

I am using JSF2 and Google Cloud SQL.

Answer (score 4):

If using Shiro's INI config, you set the SecurityManager's cacheManager property like any other bean property.  For example:

```
[main]

cacheManager = com.something.impl.SomeCacheManager
# config cacheManager as necessary, e.g.
# cacheManager.foo = bar

securityManager.cacheManager = $cacheManager
```

You can use the out-of-the-box EhCacheManager or implement the `CacheManager` and `Cache` interfaces yourself to use a custom cache backing store (e.g. Memcache, Coherence, GigaSpaces, any modern NoSQL Key/Value store, etc...)

Answer (score 1):

It seems like EhCacheManager is not part of shiro-core 1.2.1 (in the Maven package anyway). I solved the problem by adding the following to my [main] section in shiro.ini:

```
[main]
builtInCacheManager = org.apache.shiro.cache.MemoryConstrainedCacheManager
securityManager.cacheManager = $builtInCacheManager
```

Comment: Hi Allan - we can't force Ehcache dependencies on all Shiro users, so Ehcache support is provided as a [plugin](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cshiro-ehcache).  Just add it to your runtime classpath and you can use the EhCacheManager right away.  HTH!

Comment: Ahh, didn't know that. I though when you mentioned that it was out-of-the-box that it was included in the core library. Thanks!